# Does array_merge preserve order?

Tags: php

I have two arrays :

```
$arr = ["ham", "beef", "testing1"];
$arr1 = ["baby", "chicken", "wax"];
```

When merging them I get the following result :

```
var_dump(array_merge($arr, $arr1));
// ["ham", "beef", "testing1", "baby", "chicken", "wax"]
```

As you can see, the order is kept and they're added at the end of the first array. Can I be SURE that this is ALWAYS the case? Or the order is not necessarily kept? I found nothing in [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) about the order of the results.

Comment: this will merge according to this formation `(array 1, array 2)` or `(array 2, array 1)` as per your position.

Comment: The documentation already explains this as https://stackoverflow.com/a/55143529/2191572 pointed out but one thing to be aware of is how it will not preserve numeric keys. Try `$arr = [ 1=>"ham", 'g'=>"beef", 3=>"testing1"];`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I see .. I'll have to do more testing on keys if I start using any. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read more in [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

> Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.

So as you can see the values of second array are appended to the end of the previous one.

For duplicate keys the last one will override the previous one as it states in documentation:

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

Comment: Oh thanks! I actually hadn't understood it well till I re-read it now in your answer, cheers!

Comment: The caveat is that if you have associative arrays the 2nd array keys might replace the keys from the first array. There doesn't seem to be any guarantee about the order that the replaced keys appear in but I'd argue that when using associative arrays the order should really not matter.